# Paypal multicurrency issue payment status pending

Tags: php, paypal

I got issue while integrating paypal ipn , i works fine when payment is done in USD but when payment done in GBP or EUR paypal send :

```
pending_reason=>multi_currency
pending_reason=>multi_currency
```

why so i want to receieve funds in 3 currecny USD, GBP and EUR why there is problem with GBP and Eur , please guide how can i fix it

Answer (score 3):

When an account receives a new currency, PayPal holds that payment until the account owner decides whether to open a balance in that currency, convert it automatically to their primary currency, or refuse the payment. See:

https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/sell/mc/mc_receive-outside

So go into the receiver account and accept the payment to open a balance in the currency and this won't happen to future payments in those currencies.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, you could create an array with all valid currencies that you accept for payment, and then check that mc_currency is in that array when it is passed via the IPN.

```
$valid_currency = array("USD", "GBP", "EUR");
if(!in_array($_POST['mc_currency'], $valid_currency) {
    // Not a valid currency according to your list
} else {
    // Is a valid currency according to your list
}
```

[Click here](http://www.domainavenue.com/paypal_ipn.pdf) to read more about Paypal IPN. (Page 5 describes IPN Variables)